# URL Percent Encoding (URI Escaping) in Perl

Tags: perl, url, escaping

Can anyone tell me where I can find encoding functions like

encode("ram@yahoo.com") ==> ram%40yahoo.com

and decode("ram%40yahoo.com") ==> ram@yahoo.com

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Use the [URI::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/URI%3a%3aEscape) module from the `URI` distribution, which is used by pretty much everything.

Comment: There is also a compatible variant for greater speed: [URI::Escape::XS](http://p3rl.org/URI::Escape::XS)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `uri_encode` and `uri_decode` functions in the [URI::Encode](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI-Encode/) package.